# I can't programmatically change route in react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, mobx

I'm trying to programmatically redirect to a new route/component after creating a model. `<Link>` components work as expected. I'm using MobX. This was working before when I was using Redux. It stopped working when I moved to MobX. Clicking on the `<Link>` components will work as expected.

Rendered component:

```
    <Router history={locationStore.history}>
      <div>
        <SideBar />

        <div className={mergeClass('app-content text-center', { expanded: layoutStore.sidebarOpen })}>
          <NavBar />

          <div className='page-wrapper'>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home} key='home' />,
            <Route exact path='/stuff/:id/edit' component={StuffEdit} key='stuff.edit' />,
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
```

Location store:

```
import { observable } from 'mobx'
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

const history = createBrowserHistory()

class LocationStore {
  @observable history = history

  goTo (url) {
    this.history.push(url)
  }
}

export default new LocationStore()
```

This is where I attempt to change route:

```
return Api.post('/stuff', formData).then((response) => {
  stuffStore.addStuff(response.data)
  locationStore.goTo(`/stuff/${response.data.stuff.id}/edit`)
})
```

The url changes in the browser, but the component remains on the original page. Clicking on the generated `Link` component to the new model works as expected (without refreshing).

React version: 15.6.1
React router version: 4.1.2
Mobx version: 3.2.2
Mobx-react version: 4.2.2

Comment: have you tried using push from react-router-dom?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this

```js
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <Route path='path0' component={UserManage}></Route>
  <Route path='path1'>
    <Route path='path11' component={component11}></Route>
    <Route path='path12' component={component12}></Route>
  </Route>
</Route>


in component11, you can try this way to change the route:

this.props.router.push( '/path1/path12' );
```